# How do I hide/mask my IP address from my home network?

Tags: networking

I wondered if there is anyway I can hide or mask my IP address from my home network as my teenage son thinks it's hilarious to keep blocking the WiFi on my laptop which is not good when I am supposed to be home working.

I have tried to research via the internet but don't think a VPN will help with this?

Any advice please would be appreciated ( I have blocked his access until this issue is resolved!!)

Thank you

Comment: You can't hide your address, but you can change the password on the wifi admin page.

Comment: Thank you but he is not going through my router. I am obviously not phrasing the question correctly. My son does not know my router password, he has a PC and he a program which allows him to target and block any device on the network and I am presuming he is using my IP to distinguish which device

Comment: Then it would appear you need better parental controls on his machine; or remove his admin account privileges so he can't install software. You can't hide your IP address at all, from anything, anywhere, as that's what's needed to be able to answer anything you 'ask' over any 'net connection, internal or external.

Comment: Maybe you'd be better off posting a slightly different question over here ;) https://parenting.stackexchange.com/ Or do the same to him, give him a taste of his own medicine.

Comment: Try enabling a WiFi feature called guest or client isolation. That will break file sharing, network printing, etc. But nothing on WiFi should be able to interfere with other systems.

Comment: Implement firewall rules on the affected PC, blocking all traffic from your LAN subnet except for the router's IP & any other IPs the PC connects to (e.g. printer). Best way to ensure this works as intended is to configure static IPs on the router for all LAN devices & changing the [netmask](https://www.aelius.com/njh/subnet_sheet.html) to reflect how many LAN devices you have _(shouldn't be that many, as smartphones, tablets, and other IoT devices should be on their [own vLAN](https://www.forbes.com/sites/zakdoffman/2019/12/06/dont-get-hacked-warns-fbi-this-is-how-you-connect-smart-devices))_

Answer (score 0):

Just to provide an actual answer on this, from comments…

You can't hide your IP address at all, from anything, anywhere, as that's what's needed to be able to answer anything you 'ask' over any 'net connection, internal or external. This is tracked [with a certain amount of anonymity as you pass through your router into the outside world] & is needed to get any reply from every connection you make.

If you need to keep an errant child from mangling the network, your choices are
Stronger Parental Controls, or a non-admin account
Guest access only on the WiFi, preventing access to the rest of the internal network.